# Office Live Communications Server 14 Codenamed metro

Tags: ms-office-communicator

I really need some features that will possibly come with lcs14 does anyone know when it will be out? Is there a early adapter program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have fun with that - OCS is not a "you get what you wish for" product. There IS an EAP (Early Adopter Program) - started some months ago. There IS a target to release it this year. And that pretty much is it.

Features:

1. Better SIP - they plan it to be a PBX replacement

And that pretty much is it ;) Seriously.

From all the MS products, OCS is the most obscure one - in general you dont get any plans and feature news. This is really frustrating. I am in the same boat like you - and desperately waiting to see whether I can retire my IP PBX ;)

I expect a beta to hit us some poin late summer, if the OCS 13 release was any indication.